# Translate SQL JOIN query on multiple tables to data jpa Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following SQL query which is working fine. Either I need to write this query in spring-data @Query or need to execute it and map the result into object using ResultMapper ( Not sure which is the right way to do it )

This is the query

```
SELECT CR.* 
             FROM CALL_ATTEMPT_RESPONSE CAR 
             INNER JOIN ( 
             SELECT MAX(CALL_ATTEMPT_ID) CALL_ATTEMPT_ID FROM 
             CALL_ATTEMPT 
             WHERE ACCESS_ID = :accessId 
             ) AS CA 
             ON CA.CALL_ATTEMPT_ID = CAR.CALL_ATTEMPT_ID 
             INNER JOIN 
             CALL_RESPONSE CR 
             ON CR.RESPONSE_ID = CAR.CALL_ATTEMPT_RESPONSE_ID 
             AND CR.ACTIVE = 'true' 
             INNER JOIN 
             CALL_QUESTION CQ 
             ON CR.QUESTION_CD = CQ.QUESTION_CD 
             AND CQ.ACTIVE = 'true'
```

The query joins call_attempt_response with call_attempt on max(accessId) 
and joins with call_response on response_id where response is active
and joins with call_question on question_cd where question is active 
and retrieves all the call_attempt_responses.

I need to translate that into the following that uses spring data query

```
@Query("query goes here")
List<CallResponse> findResponsesByAccessId(@Param("accessId") String accessId);
```

Comment: and the classes are? because JPQL is based around entity classes and fields, not tables/columns

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks for the reply. I just realized that I cannot execute jpa query on tables unless it is categorized as native. I did not want to bring those additional tables as entities into our repo as we do not use other than fetching the responses.